# How to provide Keyboard input capability in RibbonDropDown in VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto

I have used RibbonDropDown to show list. Currently user must have to click on drop down arrow to select item of the list.

I want to set capability where user can type in DropDown box to select item same like Font selection in Ms Word.

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't expose this functionality to addins.

Comment: Is there any other control which can provide this functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can't add custom controls to the ribbon.

Comment: I don't whether I should ask here or post a new question. I am also not able to change width of the control.

Comment: You can set the [`SizeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbondropdown.sizestring.aspx) property.

Comment: But it is of Type String. How can I set integer value to it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Read the documentation. You set it to `"XXXXXXX"`. Then a string with the same size as `"XXXXXXX"` can fit in it. Yes, buggy implementation, I know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111873/discussion-between-nanji-mange-and-patrick-hofman).